# PHP. Different encoding when calling shell_exec from command line and browser

Tags: php, browser, encoding, utf-8

I have this php script:

```
<?php
  $cmd_desformat = "/usr/local/bin/process /tmp/input.txt > /tmp/output.txt";
  shell_exec($cmd_desformat);
```

Where input.txt is a UTF-8 file (checked with "file -i") containing:

```
Buenos días
```

and /usr/local/bin/process is a binary executable from a third party which I have extensively used and never got this problem.

Well, problem is that when I execute this from a browser:

```
http://localhost/test.php
```

The result output.txt is an US-ASCII file containing:

```
Buenos d?as [][
```

However, when I execute this from command line:

```
php test.php
```

The result output.txt is an UTF-8 file with the expected:

```
Buenos días [][
```

I have tried to execute from command line with user `www-data` to see if I could replicate the browser behaviour, but the result is again the correct one. I have also tried to use `exec` instead of `shell_exec` but the results are the same. Also tried with Firefox and Chrome.

I need it to work when being called from the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `bin/process` sensitive to the environment locales…?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP CLI environment is not the same as the `shell_exec` one. There are two possibilities for how to manage to get your content to return in the proper manner.

The easiest way is to just reset the environment by calling `env -i` in the `shell_exec` call.

```
<?php
  $cmd_desformat = "env -i /usr/local/bin/process /tmp/input.txt > /tmp/output.txt";
  shell_exec($cmd_desformat);
```

This may not work if the default environment is not correctly set up. If that is the case, then you may need to set it up explicitly using `putenv()`.

```
<?php
  putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8'); // Set this to the language you need
  $cmd_desformat = "/usr/local/bin/process /tmp/input.txt > /tmp/output.txt";
  shell_exec($cmd_desformat);
```

Comment: Thank you mate!! I was pulling my hair on this one... I used `putenv` and then it worked fine. OMG I was beginning to lose my sanity  I don't understand how it's not a default in PHP...